# columnDefs: [ { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 0 } ] not working with Columns

Tags: datatable

```
columnDefs: [
                { responsivePriority: 2002, targets: -1 }
            ],

columns:    [
                {title: "<?php echo lang("firstname") ?>" , "class": "text-center w100" }
            ]
```

*columnDefs not working with columns*

Answer (score 0):

*columnsDefs will not work with columns*
*So we can use another method to give responsivePriority to column*

[methods to give responsive priority to columns](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.responsivePriority)

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
responsive: true,
columns: [
            {title: "<?php echo lang("firstname") ?>" , responsivePriority: 1},
            {title: "<?php echo lang("lastname") ?>" , responsivePriority: 2},
            {title: "<?php echo lang("email") ?>" , responsivePriority: 3},
         ]} );
```